# Router can see the internet but nothing plugged into it can?

Tags: networking, router, internet

Last week Optimum came and replaced our Arris TG1672 modem with a new Arris TG1672 modem after the old one had two ports break.

Now our VOIP phones are no longer working.

The setup as it should be is the Arris modem connects to a Netgear Prosafe FVS3180.  Then a CISCO switch (which has all our phones connected to it) connects to the Netgear Prosafe.

From the diagnostics page of the Netgear Prosafe FVS21380 I can do DNS lookups of websites and ping them fine.

[image]

[image]

However, it appears that nothing plugged into the Netgear can access the internet.  Right now I am testing it with my laptop on DHCP, I get assigned a IP as expected from the prosafe, but then I cannot go online at all.

I must be missing something simple but this is driving me mad.  Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Edit 1:
@u1686_grawity - I am using the DNS servers and IP given to us by Optimum
[image]
into Netgear -
[image]

For the LAN DHCP part of the netgear we use that for assigning IP's to the phones locally from 192.168.2.100 - 192.168.2.130
[image]

My old IT coworker suggested to try `tracert  142.251.41.14` (google.com) from the router and my computer connected to the router.

From the router
[image]

and from my computer connected to the router it never found it -
[image]

I would have expected after 192.168.2.1 to have seen our modem but instead get a request time out.

So he thinks it's a routing problem.  Does that make sense?

EDIT 2: I can't fully explain it but it is working now.  Upgraded the firmware on the router and at first that made things worse.  Then I did a factory reset, which kept the newer firmware, setup my static IP and the LAN DHCP rules, and then it decided to work.  Everything works now.  No routes or anything else required.  I don't know what was different on the router settings when it had the old firmware but all I can say now is I am saving this configuration so next time I can just reload it.  Thank you all.

Edit 3:  That was short lived.  The phones came on all at once.  My one boss was able to make a call.  I went back to the server room to take a backup of the configuraiton and change a loose wire, changing the loose wire has set me back.  Now I am back to the router not seeing the modem.  I do believe I need some static route.  Does this look correct?  Router local ip is 192.168.2.1 andthe IP ending in 89 is the static IP of our modme.  I put the IP Subnet of the modem into that field and selected LAN.  Metric 2 is the lowest it will let me go.

[image]

Comment: Quick checks I'd do is ping 8.8.8.8 to confirm IPs work, and google.com to check DNS works, neither do, you're definately going to have to dig deeper but it'll help you narrow down the issue

Comment: Did you have the prior modem set up in Bridge Mode for VOIP and then is the new modem set up the same way?

Comment: What DNS servers is the router assigning you? Can you `ping` those servers? Can you ping anything _by IP address_?

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike I can ping 8.8.8.8 from the router and I am able to ping my secondary DNS IP, but not my primary DNS IP interestingly.  I just double checked the IP though and it is correctly entered.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes I can ping the secondary DNS server but not the primary one.  I can also ping 8.8.8.8 from the Netgear diagnostics page.

Comment: What are the addresses – are they both located at your ISP, or are they external, or are they internal LAN addresses? Do they match what the Netgear *itself* has received from upstream (from ISP or more likely from the Arris)? In the Netgear's LAN DHCP settings, were those servers entered manually? Finally, if the primary server isn't responding, can you at least make DNS queries to the secondary (and/or to 8.8.8.8)? Use `nslookup <domain> <dnsserver>` if you're on Windows.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I made an edit with some pictures.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to start over when you've invested so much time into solving a problem, but have you considered resetting everything and incrementally making changes to see if you can solve/isolate the problem?

Comment: @Brian yea good point.  I was on tech support for 2 hours with NetGear.  They had me update the firmware and it made the issue worse - the router couldn't even reach the internet.  I just factory reset it, put in the only information I did last time, assigning the static IP/gateway IP and the local LAN DHCP and it's working at least like it was before - the router can see 8.8.8.8 and my DNS server, but anyone plugged into the ports has zero access.

Answer (score 1):

That looks as if your new Arris modem (which I presume is in bridge mode so the Netgear is essentially handling everything else) is somehow causing your NetGear router to get a different internet ip-address than what you used to have.
And your Netgear has some static routing and/or firewall rules configured that refer to the OLD ip-address it used to have.
As a result the Netgear itself (using the new ip-settings) can get online just fine, but traffic from the local LAN isn't forwarded to the internet because of the old/new ip-configuration settings mismatch.

Comment: Ok you mentioned static routing.  That is what our old IT person said too, it was a routing issue.  There is a section for setting up static routes - but I don't know what to put.  The fields are "Destination IP Address" "IP Subnet Mask" "Interface", "Gateway IP Address" and "Metric".   Seems like I should make the interface LAN - but I am not sure nor do I know what would go in the IP sections.

Comment: Point it to the private IP address (dest) you have assigned to the router interface of the router that it needs to connect to get to the Internet.  Assign it an IP address that can talk with the private IP you assigned to the Internet router. Sometimes you can leave the gateway blank but make the metric a low value like a 1.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle - I tried making a route and posted a picture of my setup.  Stilling having difficulties.  Does it look right?

Comment: @BrianKarabinchak No, I believe you want it like this: https://i.imgur.com/MgoRJkp.png so anything going to the entire subnet will go to the Arris private IP of `192.168.2.254` since it will be the default gateway configured on your Netgear router. I really need to understand what private IP addresses you have configured on the netgear vs the Arris. The default gateway may actually need to be `192.168.2.254` if that's the private IP address assigned to it. Check a machine's default gateway once connected to the network switch LAN ports, and that's actually what you will use.

Comment: The NetGear's default gateway is the IP address assigned to the Arris modem on the trusted LAN side though if you connect network cable in and DHCP get an IP address (or check the configurations to see it's assigned IP on the `192.168.2.X` subnet. The destination needs to be the entire subnet though and not just once IP address for destination so `192.168.2.0` on the subnet of `255.255.255.0` and that should do it. Do a reboot of everything before and after if it works, and pull a cable and plug back in again too and maybe another reboot of the network routers/switches. @BrianKarabinchak

Comment: @BrianKarabinchak Actually, it might need to be the Default Gateway of the IP on the netgear, I've confused myself not fully understanding your setup. Some variation should work though with the default gateway but the other things should be key points for configuration hopefully... Good Luck! I might be confused on which router you have the static route to define. Sometimes these can cross subnets. too.

Answer (score 0):

This particular router we factory reset and tried connecting to the internet with no success.  We ended up buying a new router and that worked fine.